# Search for raspberry pi on network using Android

Tags: android, android-studio, raspberry-pi, dlna, ssdp

I am working on raspberry pi and android application in which everytime application is get opned it search for raspberry pi in network and if raspberry pi is found then do further operation else give aknwolegement to the user. I just need IP address of raspberry pi to do further process.

Solution purposed -

1. Making raspberry pi IP address static - Not applicable because application distributed from play store and dont have access to router.
2. Searching for the raspberry pi in network - Working on this.

What i tried is used SSDP, DLNA, UPNP protocol to create a server on raspberry pi and everytime app comes online search for the raspberry pi in network.

Used resourcee

1. https://github.com/resourcepool/ssdp-client
2. https://gist.github.com/ismaelgaudioso/4cff466459646e022332
3. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ismaelgaudioso/4cff466459646e022332/raw/2f9fb030790102c31bc656a960307028c28bad51/server.py
4. https://www.javatips.net/api/serket-master/serket-ssdp/src/main/java/org/saintandreas/serket/ssdp/SSDPServer.java

Here is what i have done

```
private static final String tag = "SSDP";

    private static final String query = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n" + "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n" + "MX: 1\r\n" +
            //"ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1\r\n" +
            "ST: ssdp:all\r\n"+
            "\r\n";

    private static final int port = 1900;

    String request() {

        String response = "";
        byte[] sendData;
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        sendData = query.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = null;

        try {
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250"), port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "Unknown Host Exception Thrown after creating DatagramPacket to send to server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "Socket Exception thrown when creating socket to transport data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(50000);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "IOException thrown when sending data to socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        try {
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "IOException thrown when receiving data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //the target package should not be empty
        //try three times

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Log.d(tag, "Checking target package to see if its empty on iteration#: " + i);
            response = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            Log.d(tag, "Response contains: " + response);
            if (response.contains("Location:")) {
                break;
            }
        }


        String adress = "";
        //filter IP address from "Location"
        Matcher ma = Pattern.compile("Location: (.*)").matcher(response);
        if (ma.find()) {
            adress += ma.group(1);
            adress = adress.split("/")[2].split(":")[0];
        }

        return adress;

    }
```

Using above methode and solution i was able to find out router IP address everytime but not of pi. Also gone through each of every library i can found on internet but not worked. Apart from this method if there any other way suggested will be appraciated.

Comment: and what was the code you run on the Pi?

Comment: It just java server which provide the home cloud and feed of security cams.

Comment: And you have checked that it implements an SSDP service?

Comment: From other apps i can see my pi but not from app.

Comment: The code you are showing seems to try to receive a single packet, is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for you attention but i fgured out the solution and will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now eventually i figured out the solution i will share my answer step by step. I am using ssdp protocol to find out the Pi on network where the Pi have dynamic Ip address. So i created the server in python and using android as a client. lets start with server first -

Also you can find the server script https://github.com/ZeWaren/python-upnp-ssdp-example

```
from lib.ssdp import SSDPServer
from lib.upnp_http_server import UPNPHTTPServer
import uuid
import netifaces as ni
from time import sleep
import logging

NETWORK_INTERFACE = 'wlp2s0'

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def get_network_interface_ip_address(interface='eth0'):

    while True:
        if NETWORK_INTERFACE not in ni.interfaces():
            logger.error('Could not find interface %s.' % (interface,))
            exit(1)
        interface = ni.ifaddresses(interface)
        if (2 not in interface) or (len(interface[2]) == 0):
            logger.warning('Could not find IP of interface %s. Sleeping.' % (interface,))
            sleep(60)
            continue
        return interface[2][0]['addr']


device_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
local_ip_address = get_network_interface_ip_address(NETWORK_INTERFACE)

http_server = UPNPHTTPServer(8088,
                             friendly_name="Personal Home",
                             manufacturer="Home Personal SAS",
                             manufacturer_url='http://www.example.com/',
                             model_description='Home Appliance 3000',
                             model_name="Personal",
                             model_number="3000",
                             model_url="http://www.example.com/en/prducts/personal-3000/",
                             serial_number="PER425133",
                             uuid=device_uuid,
                             presentation_url="http://{}:5000/".format(local_ip_address))
http_server.start()


ssdp = SSDPServer()
ssdp.register('local',
              'uuid:{}::upnp:rootdevice'.format(device_uuid),
              'urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1',
              'http://{}:8088/jambon-3000.xml'.format(local_ip_address))
ssdp.run()
```

This will create an exuction point for the server script.

```
import random
import time
import socket
import logging
from email.utils import formatdate
from errno import ENOPROTOOPT

SSDP_PORT = 1900
SSDP_ADDR = '239.255.255.250'
SERVER_ID = 'Personal Home SSDP Server'


logger = logging.getLogger()


class SSDPServer:
    known = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = None

    def run(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        if hasattr(socket, "SO_REUSEPORT"):
            try:
                self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
            except socket.error as le:
                # RHEL6 defines SO_REUSEPORT but it doesn't work
                if le.errno == ENOPROTOOPT:
                    pass
                else:
                    raise

        addr = socket.inet_aton(SSDP_ADDR)
        interface = socket.inet_aton('0.0.0.0')
        cmd = socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, cmd, addr + interface)
        self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', SSDP_PORT))
        self.sock.settimeout(1)

        while True:
            try:
                data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
                self.datagram_received(data, addr)
            except socket.timeout:
                continue
        self.shutdown()

    def shutdown(self):
        for st in self.known:
            if self.known[st]['MANIFESTATION'] == 'local':
                self.do_byebye(st)

    def datagram_received(self, data, host_port):
        """Handle a received multicast datagram."""

        (host, port) = host_port

        try:
            header, payload = data.decode().split('\r\n\r\n')[:2]
        except ValueError as err:
            logger.error(err)
            return

        lines = header.split('\r\n')
        cmd = lines[0].split(' ')
        lines = map(lambda x: x.replace(': ', ':', 1), lines[1:])
        lines = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, lines)

        headers = [x.split(':', 1) for x in lines]
        headers = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0].lower(), x[1]), headers))

        logger.info('SSDP command %s %s - from %s:%d' % (cmd[0], cmd[1], host, port))
        logger.debug('with headers: {}.'.format(headers))
        if cmd[0] == 'M-SEARCH' and cmd[1] == '*':
            # SSDP discovery
            self.discovery_request(headers, (host, port))
        elif cmd[0] == 'NOTIFY' and cmd[1] == '*':
            # SSDP presence
            logger.debug('NOTIFY *')
        else:
            logger.warning('Unknown SSDP command %s %s' % (cmd[0], cmd[1]))

    def register(self, manifestation, usn, st, location, server=SERVER_ID, cache_control='max-age=1800', silent=False,
                 host=None):
        """Register a service or device that this SSDP server will
        respond to."""

        logging.info('Registering %s (%s)' % (st, location))

        self.known[usn] = {}
        self.known[usn]['USN'] = usn
        self.known[usn]['LOCATION'] = location
        self.known[usn]['ST'] = st
        self.known[usn]['EXT'] = ''
        self.known[usn]['SERVER'] = server
        self.known[usn]['CACHE-CONTROL'] = cache_control

        self.known[usn]['MANIFESTATION'] = manifestation
        self.known[usn]['SILENT'] = silent
        self.known[usn]['HOST'] = host
        self.known[usn]['last-seen'] = time.time()

        if manifestation == 'local' and self.sock:
            self.do_notify(usn)

    def unregister(self, usn):
        logger.info("Un-registering %s" % usn)
        del self.known[usn]

    def is_known(self, usn):
        return usn in self.known

    def send_it(self, response, destination, delay, usn):
        logger.debug('send discovery response delayed by %ds for %s to %r' % (delay, usn, destination))
        try:
            self.sock.sendto(response.encode(), destination)
        except (AttributeError, socket.error) as msg:
            logger.warning("failure sending out byebye notification: %r" % msg)

    def discovery_request(self, headers, host_port):
        """Process a discovery request.  The response must be sent to
        the address specified by (host, port)."""

        (host, port) = host_port

        logger.info('Discovery request from (%s,%d) for %s' % (host, port, headers['st']))
        logger.info('Discovery request for %s' % headers['st'])

        # Do we know about this service?
        for i in self.known.values():
            if i['MANIFESTATION'] == 'remote':
                continue
            if headers['st'] == 'ssdp:all' and i['SILENT']:
                continue
            if i['ST'] == headers['st'] or headers['st'] == 'ssdp:all':
                response = ['HTTP/1.1 200 OK']

                usn = None
                for k, v in i.items():
                    if k == 'USN':
                        usn = v
                    if k not in ('MANIFESTATION', 'SILENT', 'HOST'):
                        response.append('%s: %s' % (k, v))

                if usn:
                    response.append('DATE: %s' % formatdate(timeval=None, localtime=False, usegmt=True))

                    response.extend(('', ''))
                    delay = random.randint(0, int(headers['mx']))

                    self.send_it('\r\n'.join(response), (host, port), delay, usn)

    def do_notify(self, usn):
        """Do notification"""

        if self.known[usn]['SILENT']:
            return
        logger.info('Sending alive notification for %s' % usn)

        resp = [
            'NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1',
            'HOST: %s:%d' % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT),
            'NTS: ssdp:alive',
        ]
        stcpy = dict(self.known[usn].items())
        stcpy['NT'] = stcpy['ST']
        del stcpy['ST']
        del stcpy['MANIFESTATION']
        del stcpy['SILENT']
        del stcpy['HOST']
        del stcpy['last-seen']

        resp.extend(map(lambda x: ': '.join(x), stcpy.items()))
        resp.extend(('', ''))
        logger.debug('do_notify content', resp)
        try:
            self.sock.sendto('\r\n'.join(resp).encode(), (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT))
            self.sock.sendto('\r\n'.join(resp).encode(), (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT))
        except (AttributeError, socket.error) as msg:
            logger.warning("failure sending out alive notification: %r" % msg)

    def do_byebye(self, usn):
        """Do byebye"""

        logger.info('Sending byebye notification for %s' % usn)

        resp = [
            'NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1',
            'HOST: %s:%d' % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT),
            'NTS: ssdp:byebye',
        ]
        try:
            stcpy = dict(self.known[usn].items())
            stcpy['NT'] = stcpy['ST']
            del stcpy['ST']
            del stcpy['MANIFESTATION']
            del stcpy['SILENT']
            del stcpy['HOST']
            del stcpy['last-seen']
            resp.extend(map(lambda x: ': '.join(x), stcpy.items()))
            resp.extend(('', ''))
            logger.debug('do_byebye content', resp)
            if self.sock:
                try:
                    self.sock.sendto('\r\n'.join(resp), (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT))
                except (AttributeError, socket.error) as msg:
                    logger.error("failure sending out byebye notification: %r" % msg)
        except KeyError as msg:
            logger.error("error building byebye notification: %r" % msg)
```

A class implementing a SSDP server.  The notify_received and
    searchReceived methods are called when the appropriate type of
    datagram is received by the server.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import threading

PORT_NUMBER = 8080


class UPNPHTTPServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    # Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):

        if self.path == '/boucherie_wsd.xml':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/xml')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(self.get_wsd_xml().encode())
            return
        if self.path == '/jambon-3000.xml':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/xml')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(self.get_device_xml().encode())
            return
        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b"Not found.")
            return

    def get_device_xml(self):
        """
        Get the main device descriptor xml file.
        """
        xml = """<root>
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <device>
        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:Basic:1</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>{friendly_name}</friendlyName>
        <manufacturer>{manufacturer}</manufacturer>
        <manufacturerURL>{manufacturer_url}</manufacturerURL>
        <modelDescription>{model_description}</modelDescription>
        <modelName>{model_name}</modelName>
        <modelNumber>{model_number}</modelNumber>
        <modelURL>{model_url}</modelURL>
        <serialNumber>{serial_number}</serialNumber>
        <UDN>uuid:{uuid}</UDN>
        <serviceList>
            <service>
                <URLBase>http://xxx.yyy.zzz.aaaa:5000</URLBase>
                <serviceType>urn:boucherie.example.com:service:Jambon:1</serviceType>
                <serviceId>urn:boucherie.example.com:serviceId:Jambon</serviceId>
                <controlURL>/jambon</controlURL>
                <eventSubURL/>
                <SCPDURL>/boucherie_wsd.xml</SCPDURL>
            </service>
        </serviceList>
        <presentationURL>{presentation_url}</presentationURL>
    </device>
</root>"""
        return xml.format(friendly_name=self.server.friendly_name,
                          manufacturer=self.server.manufacturer,
                          manufacturer_url=self.server.manufacturer_url,
                          model_description=self.server.model_description,
                          model_name=self.server.model_name,
                          model_number=self.server.model_number,
                          model_url=self.server.model_url,
                          serial_number=self.server.serial_number,
                          uuid=self.server.uuid,
                          presentation_url=self.server.presentation_url)

    @staticmethod
    def get_wsd_xml():
        """
        Get the device WSD file.
        """
        return """<scpd xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service-1-0">
<specVersion>
<major>1</major>
<minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>
</scpd>"""


class UPNPHTTPServerBase(HTTPServer):
    """
    A simple HTTP server that knows the information about a UPnP device.
    """
    def __init__(self, server_address, request_handler_class):
        HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, request_handler_class)
        self.port = None
        self.friendly_name = None
        self.manufacturer = None
        self.manufacturer_url = None
        self.model_description = None
        self.model_name = None
        self.model_url = None
        self.serial_number = None
        self.uuid = None
        self.presentation_url = None


class UPNPHTTPServer(threading.Thread):
    """
    A thread that runs UPNPHTTPServerBase.
    """

    def __init__(self, port, friendly_name, manufacturer, manufacturer_url, model_description, model_name,
                 model_number, model_url, serial_number, uuid, presentation_url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.server = UPNPHTTPServerBase(('', port), UPNPHTTPServerHandler)
        self.server.port = port
        self.server.friendly_name = friendly_name
        self.server.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.server.manufacturer_url = manufacturer_url
        self.server.model_description = model_description
        self.server.model_name = model_name
        self.server.model_number = model_number
        self.server.model_url = model_url
        self.server.serial_number = serial_number
        self.server.uuid = uuid
        self.server.presentation_url = presentation_url

    def run(self):
        self.server.serve_forever()
```

A HTTP handler that serves the UPnP XML files.
**Lets scan the Pi on network using android.**

```
 private static final String tag = "SearchPi";

    private static final String query = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n" + "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n" + "MX: 1\r\n" +
            "ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1\r\n" +
            //"ST: ssdp:all\r\n" +
            "\r\n";

    private static final int port = 1900;
```

Now lets create a new asyncTask because it is network releated process and add the below code in asyncTask

```
String response = "";
        byte[] sendData;
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        sendData = query.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = null;

        try {
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250"), port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "Unknown Host Exception Thrown after creating DatagramPacket to send to server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "Socket Exception thrown when creating socket to transport data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "IOException thrown when sending data to socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        try {
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "IOException thrown when receiving data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            response = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            Log.d(tag, "Response contains: " + response);
            if (response.contains("/jambon-3000.xml")) {
                Log.d("logCat", receivePacket.getAddress().toString());
                break;
            }
            else {
                Log.d("logCat", "Popz! Pi not found");
            }
        }
```

With above code you can also create media server on Pi.